# How to read a file in python?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, file, python-3.6

I have a file of the format .lammpstrj which has the 15 million rows of data points of the following pattern:

```
id mol type x y z
100000
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
3000
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
4.8659189006091452e-02 3.0951340810994285e+01
4.8659189006091452e-02 3.0951340810994285e+01
4.8659189006091452e-02 3.0951340810994285e+01
ITEM: ATOMS id mol type x y z 
2325 775 1 4.5602 4.35401 4.16348 
718 240 2 4.91829 3.19545 7.30041 
2065 689 2 6.51189 1.25778 5.11324 
639 213 1 6.84357 5.10011 0.530398 
720 240 1 5.46433 3.36715 6.48044 
694 232 2 0.107046 3.3119 7.42581 
1855 619 2 6.17236 4.57208 5.02607 
1856 619 1 6.65988 5.13298 5.69518
```

I want to store all this data into a pandas DataFrame. How can I do the following task?

Comment: 5 seconds googling: http://mdtraj.org/1.9.3/api/generated/mdtraj.load_lammpstrj.html Why not use this?

Comment: @AndrejKesely it is throwing the following error "top" argument is required for load_lammpstrj .

Comment: Moreover can I do a thing through which I am able to convert the file into csv?

Comment: From the documentation for `top=` parameter: `The lammpstrj format does not contain topology information. Pass in either the path to a pdb file, a trajectory, or a topology to supply this information.` It seems that you need to supply this information.

Comment: The problem is I don't have a file for topology. This is the only file with me and I have to perform some calculations on it